# Using Twilio to trigger scripts?

Tags: python, twilio

I've tried looking for this online. I have python scripts for twilio to send messages for me on results from scripts.

But is there any framework to send a message to my twilio phone number which then triggers a script remotely?

So currently I have a script that does this

```
remote server -> Twilio -> phone
```

But could I do:

```
phone sends text message -> Twilio -> Remote server -> somescript.py
```

Comment: What did your google search turn up? SO is not going to recommend services that do SMS interfaces.

Comment: You can created a api to do this. Send message(json) to your server, then your server will check your message and send message to your phone.

Comment: @Soviut Literally nothing. Just using python to make phone calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  In order to do this, your remote server must publish a REST API that can be the receiving endpoint for a [twilio webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook).  From there, you can use whatever framework you want to kick off the script from the web/app server that is servicing the webhook callback from twilio.  Two potenetial examples, since you are using python, are django and flask.  Of course, your callback endpoint URL has to be configured in your twilio account.  Good luck!